# What is the meaning of Square Icons on Branch Lines in TortoiseGit Log Graph?

Tags: tortoisegit

I have Square and Round Icons on the Branch Lines in the TortoiseGit Log Graph. What is the meaning of Square Icons?

[image: Meaning of Square Icons ON Branch Lines]

Comment: Well seems pretty obvious that is where the repos branch and merge (i.e the lines join)

Comment: Expert down voters!!

Answer (score 4):

Square = Merge Commit

Round = Commit

Answer (score 2):

In the graph line there are two types of shapes:

The circles indicate normal commits w/o any branching.

The squares indicate merges and branchings. In the first case these are merge commits (i.e., a commit with more than one parent) and in the latter case these are also normal commits. A square was chosen here to indicate that a branch goes off.

The colors of the lines (and of the shapes) are just there to make the graph better readable (i.e., to see to which branch they belong) and are configurable: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-colours3

Answer (score 0):

It's for the diverged and merged point.