# Git Tree Graph - what does Squares,circles and different colors shows?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Can Any one tell me what are different colors in the below git graph shows? Does it shows different authors? 
Square - > Show merge Points but what are different color lines?
What are circles?
Any documentations for the same?

[image]

Comment: can you please tell what is the path from black box to red circle means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of Square Icons on Branch Lines in TortoiseGit Log Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880591/what-is-the-meaning-of-square-icons-on-branch-lines-in-tortoisegit-log-graph)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors show different branches

The circles show commits

The squares show merges